# Reason of using virtual keyword on POCO method

Tags: asp.net, lazy-loading

In my Web project, I don't see any benefit using lazy loading. So I use eager loading only.

Unless I do not use lazy loading,
Is there still any reason do I need to use the virtual keyword on POCO method?

```
public class User {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Order> orders { get; ;set}
}

public class Order {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public int userId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("userId")]
    public virtual User user {get; set;}

}

// Using eager loading to avoid N+1 problem
db.Order.Include("user").Select(x => new {
    orderId = x.id,
    userName = x.User.name
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Eager load everything eh? Well, that's one way to load the entire database into memory...

Comment: Entire database into memory? I believe I just put only I queried (selected) data into memory. Could you please take a look the example codes, and please let me know if there is something I'm doing wrong.